# return array variable from csv - javascript / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm running this code from a node console and I need to put the result as a variable

```
 var csv = require('csv-array');
 csv.parseCSV("my.csv"
 , function(data){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 });
```

The array prints out fine, but how do I set the result as a variable?  (I'm hoping this is as easy as it seems for someone with experience)

Comment: I'm not big on this whole js thing, care to elaborate?  If you put it as an answer, you can grab an easy correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
 var csv = require('csv-array');
 //variable declaration
 var myVariable;
 csv.parseCSV("my.csv", function(data){
   myVariable = JSON.stringify(data);
   return data;
 });
 //take it as a variable here.
 console.log(myVariable);
```

Comment: This was actually my issue in node. 
 Thanks for the help though. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: so you just need to `return data` ? @thefett thank you